# Configuring Zend Framework 2 AbstractPluginManager

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, inversion-of-control

I've spent a little while trying to trace my way through the ZF2 code and documentation, but I can't seem to find an explanation for a way to extend the configuration using the global config for an instance of `Zend\Service\AbstractPluginManager` when it has been registered as a service manager with the service listener.

An overview of the classes I have created:

- `AssetManager\AssetFilterPluginManager`: extends `AbstractPluginManager`
- `AssetManager\Service\AssetFilterManagerFactory`:  A factory extending `Zend\Mvc\Service\AbstractPluginManagerFactory` with the `const PLUGIN_MANAGER_CLASS` set to `"AssetManager\AssetFilterManagerFactory"`
- `AssetManager\AssetFilterProviderInterface`: The module feature interface

In the `config/module.config.php` I have configured the service listener as follows:

```
'service_listener_options' => array(
    array(
        'service_manager' => 'AssetFilterManager',
        'config_key'      => 'asset_filters',
        'interface'       => 'AssetManager\AssetFilterProviderInterface',
        'method'          => 'getAssetFilterConfig',
    ),
),
```

The service manager config contains the definition of `AssetFilterManager`:

```
'service_manager' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'AssetFilterManager' => 'AssetManager\Service\AssetFilterManagerFactory',
    ),
),
```

Having read through the usage of these options in the view helpers code, this is my understanding of how the configuration should be laid out. Looking at the `config_key` option in the service listener options, it would seem that the configuration should be passed to the plugin manager to configure the services, but I can't determine where or whether this happens. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the implementation.

My goal is a pluggable service manager extension that functions much like Zend's built-in controller plugins and view helper managers. If there's anyone with any greater experience using these features than me, I would appreciate any insight.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot configured the service listener in the config/module.config.php, service_listener_options is part of config/application.config.php. This configuration is readed before modules initialization.
See work example [here](https://github.com/popovsergiy/zf2-custom-serviceManager-plugin).
You must configured the service listener in your Module.php